# Can an exterrior of a ball in Euclidean space be considered a ball itself under any proposed generalization?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, euclidean-geometry

If we take an n-dimensional Euclidean space and cut off a ball centered at origin, we get a set that has boundary equal to the surface area of the cut off ball.

I wonder whether there were any attempts or suggestions to consider such body a sphere with a kind of infinite or negative or otherwise non-real radius?

Of course, if we consider a geometry on a sphere, the circle divides the space into two disks, but what about Euclidean space? Does the Euclidean space show the part outside the sphere behaves like a ball?

What about other possible Riemannian or Minkowski spaces?

My own opinion, the resulting figure is not a sphere even if a sphere with infinite radius is permitted (particularly, they are not members of [Lie sphere geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_sphere_geometry)).

Particularly, if we take any inequality defining a ball, it seems we cannot "invert" it by just going to any limit.

Comment: What if the one-point compactification $\widehat{\mathbb{R}^n} $ the Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$; in this case the resulting space $\widehat{\mathbb{R}^n}\setminus \overline{B(x,r)}$, where $B(x,r)$ is any (open) ball centered at $x$ of radius $r$ becomes homeomorphic to ball itself.

Comment: @JackL. well, it would be another space where there are still no spheres of infinite radius, or am I wrong?

Comment: No, you’re not wrong because $\widehat{\mathbb{R}^n}$ is obviously compact.